Spark : Persist was not working as expected
I was using a PySpark DataFrame where I called a UDF function. This UDF function makes an API call and stores the response back into the DataFrame. My goal is to store the DataFrame and reuse it instead of calling the same DataFrame multiple times
df = df_source.withColumn("Id",generateid_udf(col("ExID"),col("DueDate"),col("MoxiePDMID"),col("Details"),col("Name")))

df.persist() 
data = df.collect()   
print(data)

**Merge condition **
targetDF = DeltaTable.forPath(spark, targetPath)  
(targetDF.alias("tgt")
.merge(df.alias("src"), "tgt.ExID = src.ExID" )
    .whenMatchedUpdate(set =
    {
    "tgt.Id": "src.Id",
    "tgt.UpdatedBy": lit("Created"),
    "tgt.UpdatedDate": current_timestamp()})
.execute()
)

Suppose that in the Collect action, the ID field was returning 101, but in the merge condition, it was stored as 102. I want to avoid making multiple API calls. Based on my understanding, if we cache and persist the data, it will be stored on disk, allowing us to reuse it

Using .collect() will bring the data to the Driver node, which may not be efficient if your dataset is big.
Try
df.persist() or df.cache()
cnt = df.count()
and your merge operations.
I believe your dataset has both 101 and 102 for the Merge to make use of the cached resultset.

@GaneshChandrasekaran, in my df_source dataframe, I had only one record. While applying the generateid_udf function, I received the response data as 101 for the id field. Later, while applying the merge operation, the generateid_udf was invoked again, and it generated an ID of 102. I was trying to avoid the second API call. I believe the persist was not implemented properly on the above code.

You need to persist the dataframe immediately after creating it.
Also make sure you don't execute collect before persist.
i have done below testing.
source_data = [(1,)]
df_source = spark.createDataFrame(source_data, ["ExID"])
df = df_source.withColumn("Id", add_one(col("ExID")))
df.persist()
print(df.collect())
print(df.collect())
print(df.collect())

output:
[Row(ExID=1, Id=710)]
[Row(ExID=1, Id=710)]
[Row(ExID=1, Id=710)]

And for below code.
source_data = [(1,)]
df_source = spark.createDataFrame(source_data, ["ExID"])
df = df_source.withColumn("Id", add_one(col("ExID")))
print(df.collect())
df.persist()
print(df.collect())
print(df.collect())
print(df.collect())

Output:
[Row(ExID=1, Id=675)]
[Row(ExID=1, Id=182)]
[Row(ExID=1, Id=658)]
[Row(ExID=1, Id=387)]

If you observe here, when collect is done before persist the values are changing.
So, make sure you persist immediately.
If still getting the same issue, you run the code from the beginning where the dataframe is created.
